# SQL (employees with same birthdate)

Tags: sql

i have this table:

```
name     dob
Avash   1991-07-23
Bipin   1990-03-25
Bijay   1990-03-25
```

How do I fetch a list of employees who have the same dob?

Comment: Do you know the basic SQL, like 'Select' and 'Where'? If not, I suggest you learn the basic SQL first.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE dob IN (
  SELECT dob
  FROM table
  HAVING COUNT(dob) > 1
  GROUP BY dob
)
```

The sub-query finds all dob values that occurs more than once, and then you just select all names that matches those dobs.

Comment: That would just get you a list of employees who have the same birthday as somebody else, but not the name of the other person who has that same birthday.

Comment: @mypetlion that is incorrect. The other person(s) will appear in subsequent records. I think an ORDER BY would be appropriate though so that it's clear.

Comment: @JNevill yes they would be elsewhere in the results. But I don't see the usefulness of having the records not being paired together in the results.

Comment: Your thinking "Pair" here but there may be 100 people sharing that birthday. To try to show that in columns would be inappropriate. and to only allocate two columns for name would still cause you to have to search in rows for matches.

Comment: @mypetition If you take a look at the Window Function version of this that I added as an answer you'll see it also spits out the number of folks that share that same birthday, which when searching duplicates can be very helpful as well. One could order by the `dobcount` and see what kind of a monster mess they have to deal with (assuming we are searching duplicates for data cleansing, but probably not in OPs case since DOB would make for a dumb key, unless the table was like "fact_of_the_day" or something).

Answer (score 1):

Also an option if window functions are supported in your RDBMS:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT name, dob, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY dob) as dobcount
   FROM yourtable
) sub
WHERE sub.dobcount > 1
```

This will get you similar answer to @daniel's very correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  tbl1.name
       ,tbl2.name
FROM    table tbl1
       ,table tbl2
WHERE   tbl1.dob = tbl2.dob
AND     tbl1.name < tbl2.name
```

Comment: This means two people named John who have the same bday won't return.

Comment: This also means that if 3 people have the same dob you will end up with some strange semi-cartesian product.

Comment: The table only has two columns. If they have the same name and the same birthday, there's no way to distinguish them, and it's essentially a duplicate row.

Comment: Use the table's primary key in that test. From the example shown in the question, the name seems to be the PK.

Comment: @mypetlion Which is why you should not add answers to such a poor post. You end up throwing out a solution that won't solve most cases (not your fault since OP didn't ask a good question).

Comment: I usually use `<` rather than `<>` so you don't get both `Bipin,Bijay` and `Bijay,Bipin`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this...

```
CREATE TABLE #stuff (first_name varchar(15), dob date);

INSERT INTO #stuff (first_name, dob)
VALUES ('Avash', '1991-07-23')
     , ('Bipin', '1990-03-25')
     , ('Bijay', '1990-03-25')
     , ('Mike', '2010-12-01')
     , ('Dick', '2010-12-01')
     , ('Kavitha', '1992-03-25');

SELECT s.[first_name]
     , s.dob
  FROM #stuff s
 WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT dob
  FROM #stuff
 WHERE dob = s.dob
 GROUP BY dob
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Here's what you'd get...

[image]